# Why do I get this error sometimes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to the programming world and I started to learn python.

I want to make simple quiz app but I'm stuck at the start. I can't figure out a way to print a random question and check if the answer is correct or not.

I wrote this code and sometimes it works but sometimes I get an error. Can some one explain to me what is this error and what should I do?

```py
import random

def topic_ch():
    print ("hello you have 3 topics chose your topic by preesing the topic number \n 1-random asking \n 2- quizz")
    topc = input()
    if topc == "1":
        topic_1()


def topic_1():
    set1 = {1: "who is the presedint of USA ? :\n -1 D.Trump         2-Emmanuel Macron\n -3 George W. Bush       4-Bill Clinton:",
       2:"who is the presedint of France ? :\n -1 D.Trump           2-Emmanuel Macron\n -3  George W. Bush       4-Bill Clinton:"}
    print (random.choice(set1))
    ans = input()
    for set1[1] in set1:
        if ans == "1":
            print ("correct")
            break
        else:
            print ("opss")
            break
        for set1[2] in set1:
            if ans == "3":
                print ("correct")
                break


topic_ch()
```

The error:

> python Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Raad\Desktop\oi.py", line 28, in 
>       topic_ch()   File "C:\Users\Raad\Desktop\oi.py", line 7, in topic_ch
>       topic_1()   File "C:\Users\Raad\Desktop\oi.py", line 13, in topic_1
>       print (random.choice(set1))   File "C:\Users\Raad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\random.py",
>   line 262, in choice
>       return seq[i] KeyError: 0

Comment: It randomly chose element `[0]` of the sequence.  However since this is a dict, `[0]` is interpreted as a key, not a list index, and the dict has no element with a key of `0`.  I'm not sure `random.choice()` is really intended to work directly with dicts.  It would probably work if you numbered the dict keys starting from zero instead of starting from one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice` expects a sequence - a container where you can get items out by their numerical index from 0 to one less than the length of the container (lists and tuples are examples of this). When you pass in the dictionary, it randomly chooses to select element 0 or element 1 (because the dictionary has length 2). 1 happens to correspond to a key of your dictionary, so it sometimes seems like this is working. If your dictionary keys were just numbers from 0 to 1 less than the length of the dictionary, this could work, but in general a better approach for picking a random item from a dictionary would be something like

```py
key = random.choice(list(set1.keys())
```

Note that `set1` isn't a great name for this variable because 1) it's not a set, it's a dictionary and 2) it doesn't tell us anything about what values are stored in the variable. Your code might have other problems too - feel free to ask another question if you're still not able to get it working once you incorporate this fix.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice()` requires a sequence (for example a list) as input, not a dictionary.

instead of:

`print (random.choice(set1))`

try:

```
choice = random.choice(list(set1))
print(set1[choice])
```